# Why onPress function fired 3 times in Android TV os?

Tags: react-native, expo, android-tv

I'm new to react native and I'm going to develop an application for Android TV.

I opened a new project and try some basic things. However, I found that onPress event will be fired 3 times after clicked the select button. I tried with my real device and AVD resulting the same outcome.

Can someone tell me why onPress will be fired 3 times?

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="123" onPress={() => {
        console.log('555');
      }} />
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Console

```
555
555
555
```

Answer (score 1):

https://snack.expo.io/aqnj-8iOf

If you look at the snack above which includes your code, you'll notice that it's neither logging for more than once when pressing the button.

It seems like the JavaScript bundler is logging separately from the emulator.
try to close and debugging tool and remain with the terminal only, that should do the trick.